# How to get target object from a proxy object in Salesforce Lightning?

Tags: javascript, salesforce, lightning

I am using "document.getElementsByClassName" in a Lightning JS Renderer which returns a Proxy object. I can see the actual elements which I want in the debug console but I don't how to extract that element from a proxy object.

The screenshot of debug console
[image: img]

Answer (score 0):

JSON.strigify() method will allow you to check values in proxy object. Also you can specify aura:id to the text area and you can access it using cmp.find("inputId").getElement() to get elments ehihc is the recommended in lightning.